# Should I subscribe or use backing properties, to update dependent Data in a component?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a hard time figuring out what the best practices are for Angular.

I have the following issue:

```
<div>
   <app-child [data]="data | async"> 
   </app-child>
</div>
```

Should I do the following:

A: Use Backing properties to update a related Value

```
class ChildComponent{
     @Input 
     set data(value){
        this._data =value;
        this.label = this.labelService.getLabelColor(value.warningperiod)
     }
     get data(){ return this._data}
     _data: object;

     labelColor:string
     // constuctor... 
}
```

B: Use Observables and subscriptions

```
<div>
   <!-- pass down the whole observable -->
   <app-child [data]="data"> 
   </app-child>
</div>
```

```
class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
     @Input data: Observable<object>;
      labelColor: String;
      onInit(){
         this.data
         .subscribe( value =>{
              this.labemColor= this.labelService
.getLabelColor(value.warningPeriod)
          }) 
      }
      //constructor
     
}
```

What is better?

When I subscribe I need to unsubscribe, and that is "annoying."

In which situation should I do what?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to modify asynchronous data, `AsyncPipe` is the best option because you don't have to remember about unsubscribe (avoiding memory leaks) and detect changes will be done in a backdrop.

If you have to modify data, do some actions after getting new data, in this case, subscribe in .ts is better but you have to remember about unsubscribe and if you set `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` you have to run `detectChanges`.

So, You should use `AsyncPipe` in most cases, subscribe only when you really need it.